# Creating a sequential publisher in Swift Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want to debounce a batch of events and process them after a delay of ~1.5 seconds. Here's what I've done.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var pending: [TaskInfo]
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init() {
        processPendingTasks()
    }

    func queueTask(task: TaskInfo) { 
        pending.append(task)
    }

    private func processPendingTasks() {
        cancellable = $pendingTasks
                .debounce(for: 1.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                .sink(receiveValue: { batch in 
                    // Iterate though elements and process events.
                })           
    }
}
```

**Issue:** This works fine, but the issue that I've is that it performs unnecessary view updates since the array is tagged `@Published`.

**What I'm looking for:** The ideal approach would be a streaming setup where I get all events (in a batched fashion) but the `sink` should wait exactly for 1.5 seconds after the last event was added.

I tried `PassthroughSubject`, but it seems like it only gets me the last event that happened in the last 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is a combination of a `PassthroughSubject` and the `collect` operator. In `queueTask` send the tasks to the subject.

```
func queueTask(task: TaskInfo) { 
    subject.send(task)
}
```

1.5 seconds after receiving the last item send

```
subject.send(completion: .finished)
```

and subscribe

```
subject
.collect()
.sink { [weak self] tasks in 
   self?.pending = tasks
 }
```

If the interval of the incoming tasks is < 1.5 seconds you could also use the `.timeout(1.5)` operator which terminates the pipeline after the timeout interval.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I tried it and I've only one issue now. Since I'm calling `.finished`, the sink is only called once. What I want is to continue the stream even after the sink is called, i.e. after one batch is finished processing - it should start over again listening for a new batch.

Comment: As you wrote *after the last event was added* I assumed that the transmission was finished after the last item. Alternatively you could use `collect(n)` which emits the items in chunks of n.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using the .collect(.byTime) pattern with a delay of 1.5. It works for my use case although not exactly what I asked in the question.

Comment: collect() was the missing piece that I was looking for. Thank you for that!